# ISO C++ - Is it legal to declare in a template - array or function parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, language-lawyer, c++14

I'm wondering if such constructs for a template are allowed:

```
template<typename T, T arr[4]>

template<typename T, T func(void)>
```

Latest ISO C++ 14 draft first states in § 14.1.4:

[image: ISO C++ quote 0]

As you can see the above list shows the types allowed for template parameters and there is nothing like 'functions' or 'arrays' in it. However lately at § 14.1.8 we have this (even with cited examples):

[image: ISO C++ Quote 1]

So the question is - should a compiler allow such constructs or not? Or as this is a draft - can someone compare it with the original version and say if it is the same? Maybe there is the problem.

EDIT: I'm asking for the standard paper. Is the way it's written defected?

*My personal opinion is that such idiotic and confusing constructs shouldn't be allowed in any case. Especially in C++ templates.*

Comment: Same in C++11 standard.

Comment: Isn't 14.1 (8) the answer to the question? The types are adjusted to allowed types, and then there are no more problems.

Comment: No because there shall not be any case in which a template parameter type be 'function' or 'array' one. This is guaranteed by 14.1 (4).

Comment: Why do you think this is *idiotic* and *confusing*?

Comment: Because 'array' is not a 'pointer' and imitating another type is never a wanted behavior. I've talked on the matter pretty much. If you don't understand the difference then go read about it.

Comment: Never-mind - so what do you think - is this standard defect?

Comment: @GuyGreer those templates take type parameters; FISOCPP is asking about non-type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for non-type template parameter adjustment are precisely those for function parameters, as C++14/11 **[dcl.fct]**/5 (C++03 **[dcl.fct]**/3). Likewise, the rules for function parameter adjustment of array and function types were carried over directly from C (C11 6.7.6.3/7; 8).

Changing the rules at this stage of the evolution of the language would introduce incompatibility with existing code, with previous versions of the language, with the rules for function parameters or, if those were also changed, with C, and for little benefit other than straightening out a minor quirk of the language.

If you want to see this usage deprecated I would suggest getting a warning added to gcc and/or clang for template and/or function parameter array-to-pointer and function-to-pointer conversion. The fact that this warning does not already exist suggests that most programmers do not share your opinion on this construct.

Comment: Because most programmers doesn't even know that arrays are objects themselves. A common opinion is that they are just pointer to array first element. Very few knows that they can be passed via reference or pointer. Otherwise I'm sure that they'll share my opinion. But the case here is the 'defect' in the C++ standard. You didn't say anything about it.

Comment: @FISOCPP I explained where the current behavior arises, the obstacles to changing it, and one possible pathway to getting it changed. Anything beyond this would be a matter of opinion or otherwise off-topic.

Comment: However you never answered - is this an ISO standard defect?

Comment: @FISOCPP: You seem to have a low opinion of most programmers. While the "arrays are pointers" meme seems quite common among beginners, you can't get far with the language without learning how the object model actually works, and every non-beginner I've met had a decent working knowledge of that.

Comment: @FISOCPP of course it isn't a defect. Defects are when the standard is inconsistent with itself, underspecified or impossible to implement.

Comment: I think this is the case. In the first place it states that such parameters must not exist (of type array or function) but then it describes an adjustment for them. Isn't this just exactly a defect?

Comment: @FISOCPP: No. After the adjustment, they have an allowed type. Clause 4 doesn't say that you can't specify array or function types; just that the parameter can't have one of those types. Which it won't, because of the adjustment.

Comment: I think it says just that. It tells us that 'template-parameter' (which is a 'parameter-declaration') "shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:..." It talks about the syntax - not about something abstract. The adjustment is written after this statement - so I it should obey it's rules and thus it seems to be redundant.

Comment: @FISOCPP: Clause 4 only makes sense at all if you interpret *template-parameter* as shorthand for "the semantic template parameter denoted by the *template-parameter* syntactic element", since the syntactic element can't be said to have a type. By that interpretation, clause 4 and clause 8 are consistent. (Indeed, much of the standard only makes sense if you interpret references to syntactic elements as references to the semantic concepts they denote; so if you regard that shorthand as a defect, there would be a lot of work, and a lot of extraneous verbiage, to fix it.)

Comment: That's nice. I like my name for a reason :).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if such constructs for a template are allowed

Yes, by the clauses you quote. By clause 8, the types are adjusted to pointers, which are allowed by clause 4.

> should a compiler allow such constructs or not?

Yes, because the standard says it must.

If you're asking whether the standard should allow these: yes, because changing it would break existing valid code.

> Or as this is a draft - can someone compare it with the original version and say if it is the same?

I don't have the published C++14 standard, but it's the same in [this draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) which, I believe, is more recent than the standard. C++11 and earlier standards specify the same type adjustments.

> My personal opinion is that such idiotic and confusing constructs shouldn't be allowed in any case.

They make more sense in C where such conversions are commonplace (obviously I mean that for function parameters, not template parameters, since C doesn't have templates). In C++, the confusion can usually be avoided through higher-level abstractions (`std::array` and functors), and one should only mess around with raw arrays and pointers if one knows what one's doing.

One could make an argument for deprecating the conversions in C++, since they can be somewhat confusing, and have little of the readability benefit than might justify their existence in C. But that would be highly opinionated, and off-topic here.

Comment: This is now for C++ templates. Are C++ templates being ever part of the C language. What compatibility is keeping up here? I'm really confused.

Comment: @FISOCPP: I mentioned C because that's where these type adjustments originally came from, extended to template parameters for consistency with function parameters. Sorry if that slight digression caused confusion. The compatibility is with 30+ years of existing C++ code which assumes these adjustments.

Comment: Nitpick: I wouldn't call them "clause 8" or "clause 4". They are paragraph numbers. The actual Clause 8 is about declarators; Clause 4, standard conversions.

Comment: @T.C.: Sorry, I sometimes get a bit out of my depth when it comes to hard-core language-lawyer terminology. I'm just a programmer who knows his tools.